# SQL Server Shrink

Tags: sql-server-2008, shrink

When running the Maintenance Plan Wizard to shrink a DB ... I am selecting all databases, however I have it set to shrink only when it grows beyond a specific size.

If a database grows beyond a specific size will that trigger all the databases to shrink or only the one DB that was that size?

Also do you recommend returning the space to the OS or the DB file?

Thank you.

Comment: Why did this get voted down?

Comment: Shrinking a file should be an exceptional, rare event. Not something you automate. [Please read this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, that "all databases" selection will apply the size-monitoring to all databases, it will not shrink all databases when one grows too big.

Shrinking databases is usually not recommended, as Julien pointed out; especially on an automatic basis. I have shrunk databases before but always manually, after carefully evaluating "why" it needs to happen.

Related Q & A:

[When is it OK to shrink a Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/when-is-it-ok-to-shrink-a-database)
[Should I shrink my database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72313/should-i-shrink-my-database?lq=1)