# Analyze, Vacuum equivalent for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

In Postgres, `ANALYZE` collects statistics about the contents of tables in the database, and store it. These statistics are used to determine the most efficient query plan, in PG. Running `analyze` command improves db's performance. I want to know if there is something similar in SQL Server.

Does SQL Server have commands equivalent to Postgres' `Analyze` and `Vacuum`?

If SQL Server doesn't have the exact equivalents, are there any similar commands?

If those commands do have SQL Server versions, please explain them or post links to useful documentations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand, rough equivalent of `ANALYZE` would be [`UPDATE STATISTICS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).

> Updates query optimization statistics on a table or indexed view. By
>   default, the query optimizer already updates statistics as necessary
>   to improve the query plan; in some cases you can improve query
>   performance by using UPDATE STATISTICS or the stored procedure
>   sp_updatestats to update statistics more frequently than the default
>   updates.

Quite often automatic updates of statistics is enough, but I came across few cases when I had to do it manually to get a good query plan. One common case is when rows are added to a large table and the range of values for new rows lies outside the existing statistics histogram, the so called [Ascending Key Problem](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/seek-and-you-shall-scan-part-ii-ascending-keys).

---

Rough equivalent of `VACUUM FULL` would be commands that [shrink database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189035.aspx).

> Shrinking data files recovers space by moving pages of data from the
>   end of the file to unoccupied space closer to the front of the file.
>   When enough free space is created at the end of the file, data pages
>   at end of the file can be deallocated and returned to the file system.

In many cases shrinking a database is a bad idea.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

[When is it OK to shrink a Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/when-is-it-ok-to-shrink-a-database)

The feature is there, but it should be used to address some very specific problems.

---

As [@dezso](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6219/dezso) pointed out in the comments, simple `VACUUM` command only marks pages as free for reuse in the same table, it doesn't compact the file. SQL Server does it automatically via the [Ghost cleanup background process](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth/). Actually, it is possible to [turn it off](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/turning-off-the-ghost-cleanup-task-for-a-performance-gain/). So, it looks like this Ghost cleanup process is a rough equivalent to a simple `VACUUM`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I'd say that `VACUUM FULL` equivalent would be shrink + index defrag.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively you are talking about [CREATE STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188038.aspx) in SQL Server. You are able to manually create them, however, by default in databases (unless you change the configuration on the database, or the model database) then statistics will be [automatically created by SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx) when it needs to.

Statistics are used by the SQL Server [query optimizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/) to evalute and choose execution plans. They are kept up to date by periodic automatic updates (by default) which are done based upon the number of changes within a given table, or can also be updated manually.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (UserDB, 10);

"UserDB"- the database name.
"10" -percent free space in the database.