# What's the difference between "shrink" file vs simply reducing the initial size?

Tags: sql-server, shrink

I'm totally new in *DB Administration*. So i got confused about the "file shrink" functionality offered on SQL Server Management Studio (SMSS) or via T-SQL. Why I would I need to use that "file shrink" functionality if I can simply lower the initial size of the db?

[image]

I tried to (edit) reduce the initial size of my DB and it succefully reduced my physical file of the db. Which would also work quite the same if I use that "shrink" feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That "Initial Size" label is misleading.  It's really the "current size" of the file.  Also, changing that number and clicking "OK" does a `SHRINKFILE` behind the scenes, so the two things you're comparing are actually...the same thing

Here's my copy of the StackOverflow2010 database (where the *current* size really is 9,105 MB):

[image: screenshot of the file size of 9105 MB in the SO 2010 data file in SSMS]

If I change that to "5":

[image: screenshot of the file size updated to 5 MB in the SO 2010 data file in SSMS]

And then click the "Script" button in the top left of the window, this is what SSMS generates:

```
USE [StackOverflow2010]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'StackOverflow2010' , 5)
GO
```

So the answer to your question is that these two features of SSMS do the same thing.

By the way, I highly recommend using that "Script" button in SSMS frequently as you are learning.  It's a great way to understand what the SSMS GUI is doing, and is also helpful in automating and overcoming the limitations of the user interface as you get more comfortable with T-SQL scripts.

Note that you should be wary of shrinking database files, see here for more information:

[I Need to Shrink My Database - I just freed a lot of space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/i-need-to-shrink-my-database-i-just-freed-a-lot-of-space)

[When is it OK to shrink a Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/when-is-it-ok-to-shrink-a-database)

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that MS finally removed that word "Initial" in the GUI in version 18 of SSMS (after my loud complaints :-) ). So with a more up-to-date SSMS you would potentially have been less confused.